# How to create a shape-file with M-values

Tags: java, shapes, shapefile

Using the Java classes from com.vividsolutions.jts.geom I create shape-files for points (x,y coordinate), but is there a way to create shape-files with M-values, which are called "PointZ" in other environments?

The code for creating shape features for x/y is something like:

```
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.LineString;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.MultiLineString;
...

// for point shape
Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(x,y,z));
featureBuilder.add(point); // here x,y,z is stored

// for multi-line shape
Coordinate cl[]=... some array of (x/y/z)
CoordinateArraySequence cas=new CoordinateArraySequence(cl);
LineString linestr[]=new LineString[1];
linestr[0]=new LineString(cas,geometryFactory);
MultiLineString mls = geometryFactory.createMultiLineString(linestr);
featureBuilder.add(mls);
```

So this code-snippet works good for (x/y); but how could I add M-values? There is no method like Coordinate(x,y,z,m).

Thank you for any ideas!

Comment: Following some "research" and diskussions I have found the ExtendedCoordinate - Samples from vividsolutions, which schould be capable of adding M-values:
`
    ExtendedCoordinateSequence seq = 

    (ExtendedCoordinateSequence)seqFact.create(

    new ExtendedCoordinate[] {

    new ExtendedCoordinate(x,y,z,m) });

    Geometry g = geoFact.createPoint(seq);

    Point pg=(Point)g;

    featureBuilder.add(pg);`

what does not lead to an error, but does not add the m-values to the shape file :-(

Sorry: I do not know how to format code in an answer.